# classes structure for notes application

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns

Hi everyone!

I am writing a small application for keeping different notes (memos) and has a structure of classes which I don't like. I have a **core::MemoInterface** and a **core::MemoBuilder** classes in core (implementation is not important). Then in GUI I have Some *real* memo classes (for example: **SimpleMemo**, **TodoMemo**, etc...) which know how to draw themselves and derived from **gui::MemoInterace**  and **gui::TabsBuilder** which creates a new tab in window and request each memo is to draw itself in a newly created tab.

In my implementation the **gui::TabsBuilder::Build()** calls **gui::MemoBuilder::Build()** and try use  dynamic_cast to understand that MemoInterface is from GUI. 
Actually this is the moment I don't like, and the **question is** how to improve or rewrite the structure where core::MemoBuilder doesn't know anything about GUI, but can request each memo to draw itself.

Sorry if this is not very clear. The following code may make it is more understandable.

```cpp
namespace core {
class MemoInterface {
};

class MemoStorage { ... };

class MemoBuilder {
public:
    ... some code ...
    virtual MemoInterface* Build();
private:
    MemoStorage& storage_; // put here all created MemoInterface objects
};
} // namespace

namespace gui {
class MemoInterface : public core::MemoInterface {
public:
    virtual void Draw(SomeWindowClass* dst) = 0;
};
class SimpleMemo : public MemoInterface { // draw implementation };
class TodoMemo : public MemoInterface { };

class TabsBuilder : public core::MemoBuilder {
public:
    ... some code ...

    virtual core::MemoInterface* Build() {
         // I don't like dynamic_cast, think that it's not a good oop way 
         gui::MemoInterface* memo = dynamic_cast<gui::MemoInterface*>core::MemoBuilder::Build();

        if (!memo)
            throw std::exception();

        memo->Draw(wnd_); // or Draw(wnd_->createNestedTab()->window()) it doesn't matter

        return memo;
    }

private:
    SomeWindowClass* wnd_;
};

} // namespace gui
```

Comment: Just FYI: What you name a `realization` is called an `implementation`

Comment: Please could you clarify exactly what your question is?

Comment: @PeterR.Bloomfield, added! Repeat here: I would like to know how to improve or rewrite this structure when core::MemoBuilder doesn't know anything about GUI but can request to core::MemoInterface to draw (or other action) itself. Any ideas/suggestions would be good.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the template parameter to the dynamic_cast is gui::MemoInterface*, not core::MemoInterface* since core::MemoBuilder::Build() already returns core::MemoInterface*.

From the code you have, it appears that the only difference between a SimpleMemo and a TodoMemo is visual because they are both subclasses of the same base. Is there some member data in core::MemoInterface that differentiates a SimpleMemo from a TodoMemo?

It seems like I have more questions/assumptions than answers, so here is a suggestion: Make the relationship between SimpleMemo and core::MemoInterface a HAS-A (containment). You can still derive SimpleMemo from gui::MemoInterface if you like. Do the same for TodoMemo. Then define a factory method that takes as a parameter a core::MemoInterface*. It creates the appropriate type of memo (SimpleMemo or TodoMemo) based on the information in the supplied core::MemoInterface*:

```
class GuiMemoCreator
{
public:
    static gui::MemoInterface* CreateGuiMemo(core::MemoInterface* pMemo)
    {
        gui::MemoInterface* pGuiMemo = NULL;
        if ( pMemo->_id == SIMPLE )
        {
            pGuiMemo = new SimpleMemo(pMemo);
        }
        else if ( pMemo->_id == TODO )
        {
            pGuiMemo = new TodoMemo(pMemo);
        }
        return pGuiMemo;
    }
};
```

Then your TabsBuilder::Build() function can call the GuiMemoCreator::CreateMemo() function to build the objects you want to draw.